# Google maps API error

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps

I'm trying to generate and API javascript key for google maps to put in my project, i generated they key but it gives me the follwing error: InvalidKeyMapError
Here is my script code:

```
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBgeepqF19Lq0I2jhEWj88uafs55jmnFso;sensor=false"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

***updated***

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBgeepqF19Lq0I2jhEWj88uafs55jmnFso&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete" async defer></script>
```

where *initAutocomplete* would be your google map initialization method.

Comment: the whole map disappeared and it gave me this error Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined